# Arakelov class group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In book Neukirch Algebraic Number theory. Chapter III theorem 1.12.

If $K$ is a number field then $O_K^*$ is finitely generated and $cl_K(\mathcal O_K)$ is a finite group.

Theorem 1.12 say that $CH^1(\bar{\mathcal O})^0$ is compact if and only if $O_K^*$ is finitely generated and $cl_K(\mathcal O_K)$ is a finite.

My question is if do you  know a proof that $CH^1(\bar{\mathcal O})^0$ is compact not merely a equivalence.

Thank you all.

Comment: I do not have that book in front of me. Is that the group of idele classes of norm 1? If so, the usual proof of its compactness is to prove that $O_K^{\times}$ is finitely generated and the class group of $K$ is finite, and then prove one direction of that equivalence. Weil found a method of more directly proving the compactness, but it is harder than the usual proof.

Comment: @KCd can you link to Weil's method?  I am not familiar with it.

Comment: It is in his book Basic Number Theory.

Comment: @KCd, page of the proof ? thanks

Comment: Look at the treatment of ideles in chapter IV.